# Is it possible to get the current length of an array stored in state inside an interval running in useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a situation where I need to output a certain amount of elements on user's action (let's say click), every element has to appear 500ms after the previous element. 
Array of elements is stored inside the state, new elements are added inside setInterval running inside useEffect hook.

Here is the problem: inside the hook and interval I don't have an access to the length of the array and it can't be passed as a dependency since it would result in an infinite loop. But I have to stop the interval after there are a certain amount of elements already displayed.

I found a solution to the problem by keeping setInterval iteration inside the hook. I wonder if that's correct or there is a better/more idiomatic approach.

I created a simple example of the problem on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xo879wn08z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the interval in state updater callback where you will have access to the numbers array

```
setNumbers(numbers => {
    if (numbers.length === 9) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    return [...numbers, Math.random()]
 });
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/1yvkxwzwk3)**

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of using setInterval, you use setTimeout. You'll create a new timeout each time, but only if the length is less than 10.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let id;
    if (isCounting && numbers.length < 10) {
      id = setTimeout(() => setNumbers([...numbers, Math.random()]), 500);
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, [isCounting, numbers]);
```

Comment: This way useEffect would run on every re-render since array is always non-equal. If we'd have a more complex check it could be expensive to run it on every re-render. It works, but I don't think this is how the hooks we're meant to be used 

Comment: `This way useEffect would run on every re-render since array is always non-equal.` Yes, that's what i was trying to do. I want it to create a new set timeout every time, which means running the effect every time. Only once it reaches a length of 10 does it stop changing, and thus stop running the effect. `I don't think this is how the hooks we're meant to be used` If this doesn't meet your needs, that's fine. But i'd argue that running effects every time is exactly the way effect hooks are meant to be used. Skipping them is an optimization.